# Are all papers published by ACM indexed in DBLP?

Tags: acm, scopus

Will a paper accepted by a new conference, whose proceedings will be published by ACM and indexed in Ei Compendex and Scopus, **also be indexed in [DBLP](http://dblp.uni-trier.de)**?

In particular, will the proceedings of [ICCBDC](http://www.iccbdc.org/) be indexed in DBLP?

Comment: "and got the answer alone" - if you got the answer, why don't you post it here? You can answer your own questions.

Comment: In general, a reliable way to find out in the case of DBLP would probably *not* be by asking the conference organizers, but the people who curate DBLP.

Comment: In the past, I've sent the curator of DBLP an ACM journal which they failed to index.   They promptly changed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this question can be answered via DBLP's FAQ, specifically: [What are the criteria for dblp to index a journal or conference?](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/faq/What+are+the+criteria+for+dblp+to+index+a+journal+or+conference.html) In a nutshell,

- DBLP has a venue application and review process that seems to be applied to each newly included venue,
- During this process, a set of minimum standards for newly included venues is considered. One of these standards seems to be inherently fulfilled by conferences published in the ACM digital library: *''All full-texts of contributions should be available online (either openly or as a paid service) in an established digital library.''*
- There are no guarantees for (timely) inclusion: *''Please note that beside the eligibility of a publication venue, the workload and the resources at dblp are always a limiting factor for the inclusion of new venues''.*